# On what servers run the stackoverflow.com and serverfault.com sites?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx

I checked the server responses of the both sites and the "Server:" header title was missing completely. Surely it's cool enough to hide your server string, but I'm still curious what is it? Apache? Nginx? Come on, tell me!

Comment: Off topic but doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: so if this is offtopic, where would be the right place to ask it then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: reminds me .. i need to update that ...